# Should the plural `offset` parameter be replaced by code when using ICU Message syntax?

Tags: unicode, internationalization, translation, globalization, icu

The [ICU Message syntax](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/messages) is quite powerful and one of its plural options is to `offset` a variable that is used to determine the plural form.

I can imagine how this would be used, but it seems like this feature is easy to replace by code (pseudocode to show as an example - [try it here](https://format-message.github.io/icu-message-format-for-translators/editor.html?m=You%20worked%20for%20%7Bcount,%20plural,%20offset:1%20one%20%7B%7Bcount%7D%20hour%7D%20other%20%7B%7Bcount%7D%20hours%7D%7D%20today.&trainers=2)):

```js
icuFormat('You worked for {count, plural, offset:1 one {{count} hour} other {{count} hours}} today.', {count: workedHours});
```

```js
icuFormat('You worked for {count, plural, one {{count} hour} other {{count} hours}} today.', {count: workedHours+1});
```

In a nutshell, instead of adding more markup to the ICU syntax to do simple variable offsetting, why not offset the variable itself and keep the ICU markup leaner?

Is there some sort of use case I am missing which would make `offset` useful or would it be fair that if the goal is to keep the markup simple for translators, it would be best to avoid using `offset`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the lack of answer over the past week and the bounty I offered, I think it is fair to presume that avoiding the `offset` syntax while using ICU is probably a good idea. If you have evidence against this answer, please post your answer!

**Nov 14 2019 edit:**
After trying to find an example following @Luckylooke's answer, there might be funky implementations in some libraries but overall, unless `offset` was implemented to avoid some "ugly code" in some languages, we have no evidence yet that it is required to solve real use cases.

Answer (score 0):

There is one example from here: http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/messages

If you do offset in program it will not be working for negative numbers.. -1 in mentioned example.

You will get: `Error in render: "SyntaxError: Expected integer but "-" found."`

You can prove me wrong :)

EDIT:
Example reporoduced: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-tlteb

Comment: Which library is this? I tried a few JavaScript libraries and having negative values was easy to support without offset. Could you provide more details?

Comment: I have used this lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/messageformat in my vue project.

Comment: ok, give me few days, I will create public exmple on codepen or something

Comment: Great looking forward to it!

Comment: Edited answer with example included.

Comment: Just had more thoughts around this and are you saying you would like to set explicit plural rules on negative values? From what I understood, negative plural rules should be treated as absolute value since the rules are the same in all languages (so far). Maybe this case would be better solved using a parent `select` statement? It also looks like a very unusual edge case unless I'm missing something?

Comment: t is example taken from official docs and I was just thinking how could you achieve same result without using offset.. I do not know how real the example is.. but it can be example that maybe there are also real cases where offset cannot be omitted ;)

Comment: I think  thay setting explicit plural rules on negative numbers is a different problem and it probably should be covered with `select` since as per the specifications `1`=== `-1` in plural statements. But your example made me think that there might be languages (like C?) where adding offset "on the fly" with variables is more verbose and could make ugly code. But I still believe this is not a concern that should be exposed to translators and unless you can think of another example I will leave my answer as-is for now.